# Graph not looking how it should Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

So I am trying to reconstruct this graph of the day lenght depending on the day of the year:

[image: Graph of the day lenght depending on the day of the year]

The graph follows the formula

[image: Formula]

The function depends on day of the year t and little theta which is latitude. Other informations are given: big THETA is inclination of the earth's axis which is 23.4°, T_24 is lenght of the day which is 24 hours, T_365 lenght of the year which (in days) is 365*24. t0 is the first day of the spring and that is 79 days *24 hours.

We define chi seperately

[image: chi]

because of this dependence

[image: because of this dependence]

Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import *

THETA=np.radians(23.4)
T24=24
T365=365*24
t0=79*24

ts = np.linspace(0, 365, 100)
thetas = np.linspace(-90, 90, 100)
t, theta = np.meshgrid(ts, thetas)

z=T24*(1-arccos(tan(np.radians(theta))*sin(THETA)*sin(2*pi*(t-t0)/T365)/sqrt(1-(sin(THETA))**2*(sin(2*pi*(t-t0)/T365))**2))/pi)

CS = plt.contour(t, theta, z)
```

I still haven't included the distinction of chi because I encountered problems even earlier. So, the problem is that the graph is not looking how it should, I only get 7 horizontal lines.

Comment: The thetas should be in *radians* not *degrees*.

Comment: As far as I know the StackOverflow policy is that urgency of the asker is not really a factor, that is sometimes sad, but the idea is basically that problems of one person can help the next one.

Comment: I did not know that, @WillemVanOnsem , I am new to Stackoverflow, but thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that unit of time in the equation is hours. So `ts` must be in units of hours:

```
ts = np.linspace(0, 365, 100)*24
```

Comment: That is what I was missing, thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! Since I agree that this probably is not a question that will be useful to others, should I delete it?

Comment: Whether or not a question is useful for others cannot be verified a priori. It can be falsified, if the question does not allow for the problem to be clear. Here the problem is clear and a [mcve] is provided. Potentially someone wanting to plot the length of days with matplotlib in the future, might indeed find the question useful. The question is also not due to a typographical error, but rather the wrong units used in the maths. So this is definitely an edge case. Feel free to discuss this on meta if needed.